# How to recover from decodeURI(encodeURIComponent(originalString))?

Tags: javascript, encodeuricomponent, decodeuricomponent

- I have some legacy code (pre-React) that encodes part of a URL with `encodeURIComponent` before calling `history.push()` on the https://www.npmjs.com/package/history module in order to navigate to that URL.
- `history.push()` inside `history.js` then uses `decodeURI` to decode the entire URL partially (`decodeURI` only decodes the same characters that `encodeURI` encodes)
- this partially decoded location.pathname ends up in ReactRouter where `useParams()` gives me the partially decoded URL component back again.

Now I'm stuck with a partially decoded URL component which I cannot use. I need it fully decoded.

I can't use `decodeURIComponent` on the partially decoded string, because the original string might contain a `%`, in which case this `%` will already be decoded in the partially decoded string and this would cause `decodeURIComponent` to crash with a `Uncaught URIError: URI malformed`.

My options seem to be:

- use `unescape` to fully decode the partially decoded string (it doesn't complain about the single `%`) even though its use is discouraged (why?)
- manually re-encode any `%` (that isn't followed by a digit and a subsequent hex character) back to `%25` and then run the result through `decodeURIComponent`

Are there any less ugly solutions that I haven't thought of yet ?

EDIT : I was asked for examples of what I meant by partially decided string

```
const original = 'A-Za-z0-9;,/?:@&=+$-_.!~*()#%';
const encodedURIComponent = encodeURIComponent(original); // "A-Za-z0-9%3B%2C%2F%3F%3A%40%26%3D%2B%24-_.!~*()%23%25"
console.log(decodeURIComponent(encodedURIComponent)); //  "A-Za-z0-9;,/?:@&=+$-_.!~*()#%"
const partiallyUnescaped = decodeURI(encodedURIComponent); // "A-Za-z0-9%3B%2C%2F%3F%3A%40%26%3D%2B%24-_.!~*()%23%" - notice the '%25' at the end was decoded back to '%'
console.log(unescape(partiallyUnescaped)); // "A-Za-z0-9;,/?:@&=+$-_.!~*()#%"
//console.log(decodeURIComponent(partiallyUnescaped)); // error
```

EDIT 2: In case it can be of any help, here's a more realistic example of some of the characters our URL might contain, but because it's user generated, it could be anything really:

```
  console.log(                             encodeURIComponent('abcd+%;- efgh'))  ; // "abcd%2B%25%3B-%20efgh"
  console.log(                   decodeURI(encodeURIComponent('abcd+%; -efgh'))) ; // "abcd%2B%%3B- efgh"
//console.log(decodeURIComponent(decodeURI(encodeURIComponent('abcd+%; -efgh')))); // Error: URI malformed
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'partially'. Can you show an example?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible.  I think the string becomes ambiguous, doesn't it?

Comment: @apena I added an example I had at hand ... maybe not the best, but I hope it shows the main problem with the decoded '%' sign.

Comment: `unescape` or a manual decoder wouldn't help either, imagine your input contains literally `%25`, encodedURIComponent would make it `%2525`, then `decodeURI` would make it `%25` and finally `unescape` would convert it to `%`, losing the original `%25`.  Now, can you please clarify what parts of the URL your "legacy code" is encoding? That's what you need to fix so it encodes correctly only the parts required. (note: looking at the lib's repo, [they seem to have fixed related issues](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/pull/790/commits/815014857624e9d00a6b8c213aa86ada4814a51e)